# Why can I not set this state in React?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to set the state in my React component so that it changes upon a change in the input value of it's child. I can console.log both `event.target.name` and `event.target.value` and get the expected strings, but I can not compile this `handleChange` function:

```
handleChange: function(event){
    this.setState({event.target.name: event.target.value});
  },
```

I am confused because I am getting the error: `Unexpected Token` in the line that is my `this.setState({event.target.name: event.target.value});` statement.

My child components look like:

```
<div className='inputrow'>
    <label className='orange'></label>
    <label className='inputname'>Company</label>
    <input name='company' onChange={this.props.handleChange} className='inputtext'></input>
</div>
```

My getInitialState is:

```
getInitialState: function(){
    return {
        'company': '',
        'sensor': '',
        'trigger': '',
        'sourceip': '',
        'sourceport': '',
        'destip': '',
        'destport': '',
        'sourcename': '',
        'destname': '',
        'comments': '',
        'creator': ''
    };
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

Until ES6 you can't use dynamic keys in object literal.

```
handleChange: function(event){
  var obj = {};
  obj[event.target.name] = event.target.value;
  this.setState(obj);
},
```

Comment: this.setState({[event.target.name]: event.target.value}); also works. But what the syntax is? I don't know it, do you know it?